# Mpg123 errors in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, audio, mp3

I installed mpg123 in Ubuntu 14.04. I tried playing a song with

```
mpg123 Song.mp3
```

and I got this error:

```
[oss.c:172] error: Can't open default sound device!

[audio.c:643] error: failed to open audio device

[audio.c:180] error: Unable to find a working output module in this list: oss

[audio.c:545] error: Failed to open audio output module
```

Anybody know what it means or how I can fix it? Is it not properly configured?